# character encoding of a framed document was not declared

Tags: firefox, character-encoding, document, declare

I get this warning in FF when developing a site of mine. I can't find any real info about it and how to fix this.

```
the character encoding of a framed document was not declared. The document may appear different if viewed without the document framing it.


...e)});else for(var g in a)ca(g,a[g],c,e);return d.join("&").replace(bD,"+")}}),f....
```

jquery....min.js (line 4)

Comment: What did you do to get the error message?

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela -> 

http://www.nicesprites.se/

If you look at the intro you will se the error message after a while, try taping the intro button in the upper right corner to watch it more than one time.

Comment: I did not see any error message. In the Firefox error console, there is a large number of warnings (about different matters, not this) and no error messages. But there are some markup errors in HTML; you might start with fixing them, see http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.nicesprites.se%2F (Nothing serious though, I guess; “No explicit character encoding declaration has been seen yet (assumed utf-8) but the document contains non-ASCII.” can be fixed by moving the `meta charset` element before `title`.)

Comment: Wierd, maybe my browser that is acting up!! Thx though!

Comment: "I get this error" WRONG - it is just a warning, not really a significant problem.

Comment: It is when you use an old version of IE @SteveJones...

Answer (score 12):

You need to put

`<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">`

In the head of the iframe or whatever charset encoding you are using.

Comment: you mean <iframe content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" ...> ?

Comment: i had `<meta charset="utf-8">` this meta tag earlier. why does this can't work?
but the old pattern mentioned above by you worked.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, it looks like you are serving a javascript file. In order to set the character encoding, you have to set it in the `Content-Type` HTTP header when serving the javascript file.

E.g:

```
Content-Type: application/javascript; charset=utf-8
```

However, if you are using an `<iframe>` element to reference javascript, then you are doing it wrong.

You should only use an `<iframe>` to display something, like HTML, text, SVG, PDF etc.

For an HTML document you can, inside the `.html` file, set the character encoding with a `charset` attribute on [the `<meta>` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta#attr-charset) and on [a `<script>` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-charset). Note that the latter is deprecated and all modern browsers will read the `<meta>` tag of the document referencing the script.

#### Examples

*iframed.html*

```html
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
  <script src="jquery....min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <!-- note: setting charset on a <script> tag is deprecated -->
</head>
```

*index.html*

```html
<body>
  <iframe src="iframed.html">
</body>
```

If you have access to your web server, then you can set the character encoding as part of the response with `Content-Type` and you do not need to specify it in your documents.

- HTML: `Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8`
- JS: `Content-Type: application/javascript; charset=utf-8`
- JSON: `Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8`
- text: `Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8`

In [nodejs](https://nodejs.org/) you use the `setHeader` method on the `Response` object.

```js
response.setHeader ('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8')
```

#### DevTools

You can use your browser's DevTools to inspect the network request and check the value of `Content-Type` header. See screen shot below.

[image: Screenshot of the Network tab in DevTools, displaying the Content-Type header of jQuery]