# The character encoding of a framed document was not declared

Tags: javascript, html, css

So, i've been searching in everywhere for a resolution to my problem, but i think i've tried everything but my code is not working at all.

I'm trying to put some text of a txt file in a iframe, and it's actually reading it, but, when i try to change the css, appears the message in the title: "The character encoding of a framed document was not declared."

This is my code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE  html>
<html lang = "pt">
<head>
    <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
h1{
    position: absolute;
    left:85px;
    top:0px;
}
.LOGO{
    position: absolute;
    width:70px;
    height:70px;
    z-index: 2;
}
.portugal{
    position: absolute; 
    top: 65px; 
    left: 0px; 
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    z-index: 1; 
}
.PT01{
    position: relative;
    top: 438px;
    left:560px;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    z-index: 3;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    var x = document.getElementsByTagName("PT01");
    if(x.id == 'PT01'){
        $("#div1").css("border-style","none");
        $("#div1").css("position",'relative');
        $("#div1").css("top",'315px');
        $("#div1").css("left",'535px');
        $("#div1").css("width",'auto');
        $("#div1").css("height",'auto');
        $("#div1").css("zIndex",'4');
    }

</script>

    <img class = "LOGO" src = "http://www.chronopost.pt/sites/all/themes/custom/quimera/favicon.ico"/> <h1> Informações Package Chronopost </h1>
    <img class = "portugal" src = "http://s2.thingpic.com/images/HV/9N2YRDXBuosfkppy9Jut8Tvx.png"/> 
    <img class = "PT01"  name = "PT01" src = "http://www.chronopost.pt/sites/all/themes/custom/quimera/favicon.ico"/>
    <iframe id='div1' src = "PT01.txt">
    </iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

I hope you can help me with this! I'm just a student and i'm trying to learn more.
Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [character encoding of a framed document was not declared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13491641/character-encoding-of-a-framed-document-was-not-declared)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible duplicate [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13491641/character-encoding-of-a-framed-document-was-not-declared)

You can try this, add this between your `iframe` tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! You mean like this? : <iframe id='div1' src = "PT01.txt" >
 <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
 </iframe>